# How to set the height of a division to the height of the window in CSS?

Tags: html, css, height

I have a division that must cover the total with and height of my screen (window).
for example:
HTML:

```
<div id="all"></div>
```

I am trying to accomplish something like this:

```
#all{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
```

I believe this is not possible since CSS cannot calculate the size of the window if the document is not filling it up completely. Please correct me if I am wrong, this is just a theory. If my theory is correct, is it possible to set the height of the body to 100% of the window height by default so it can work?

Something like:

```
body{
 height:100%
}
```

I know how to accomplish this with Jquery o JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#div').css({
    height:$(window).height(),
    width:$(window).width()
 });
});
```

But I am trying to figure out if this is possible with pure CSS. Any thoughts? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
html, body, #all
{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: See my edit, now its only the `html` and `body` elements, and elements with an `id` equal to `#all`. If you want to break the `div` out of the regular document flow, you should go with an absolutely positioned option instead.

Comment: And yes, you *can* select the `html` tag inside CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify a `0` value for `right` and `bottom` too.

```
#all { top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; position:absolute; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by absolute positioning of the element.

```
.fullHeight
 {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0px; 
  bottom: 0px;
 }
```

apply this class to element for which you want to set 100% of window height.